# Create table in Microsoft SQL Server based on Distinct result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

My use case is to create rows for every month based on result set of distinct values which doesn't contain a YYYYMM date attached to it.

Example distinct data result set

columns: Name, Age, Working Hours

- Miquell, 25, 160

Expected Result

columns: Name, Age, Working Hours, Date(YYYYMM) for 2 years per month (202001, 202002, 202003 etc)

```
Miquell, 25, 160, 202001
Miquell, 25, 160, 202002
Miquell, 25, 160, 202003
```

Can this be done in a easy solution? Copying the data with a timestamp and keep on adjusting and adding to a temp table when i change the month values doesn't seem very user friendly.

Thanks for the help,

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE that computes the date and finally join to the row(s) you have.

```
WITH
Recursion AS
(
SELECT CAST('2020-01-01' AS date) AS D
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, D)
FROM   Recursion
WHERE  D < '2100-12-01'
)
SELECT 'Miquell' AS Name, 25 AS Age, 160 AS WorkingHours, CONVERT(CHAR(6), D, 112)
FROM   Recursion
OPTION (maxrecursion 0);
```